# How search impression share is calculated in Google Adword?

Tags: google-ads, impressions, cpc-ads

As per Google Adword,

*Search Impression share is the impressions that you’ve received on the Search Network, divided by the estimated number of impressions that you were eligible to receive.*

I want to know how the "eligible impression share" is calculated in google adword. If someone explain with example, It will be great.